# Two domain site: Link base URLs point to wrong domain

Tags: urls, links, domain, site-url

I have been running domain.co.za, but recently purchased domain.com. Both domains now point to the same Wordpress site. On domain.com pages all the links point to domain.co.za and on domain.co.za all the links point to domain.com, so it flip-flops between the two domains.

I am wanting both domain.co.za and domain.com links to point to domain.com.

I have set the site address to domain.com, but I have had to leave the WordPress address at domain.co.za otherwise I can't log in.

Any help to get all links to point to domain.com and stop the flip=flopping would be appreciated.

www.puresweetjoy.co.za and www.puresweetjoy.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that my hosting company had copied domain.co.za to domain.com rather than pointing both domains to the same installation. I was able to update the site URL of domain.co.za to domain.com so all of its links went to domain.com, but I couldn't log in to domain.com so all of its links pointed to domain.co.za, causing the flip flopping. It was my (bad) assumption that I only had one site running.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install plugin duplicator and create a snapshot than with the install.php and related zipped file you need to copy in a subdir or in the root (copy all site an db in local for secure restoring) the two file and launch install.php, in a wizard there is a step in wich you can ridefine the path of your doman so you can recreate all your wordpress site on .com domain to stop flipping effect.
good luck!!!